# Using VBA code to change a check box from no to yes

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I've created a button in an MS access form to create a prepopulated email. as part of this some of the fields on the form change. the only field that doesn't do what I want it to is a checkbox.

could someone tell me what I haven't done correctly please? I've tried using yes and true instead of 0.1, none of which work so I think I'm not defining "transferredTick" correctly.

```
Private Sub TransferDanRBTN_Click()

    Dim RecordID As Variant
    Dim Title As Variant
    Dim FirstName As Variant
    Dim LastName As Variant
    Dim Address1 As Variant
    Dim Address2 As Variant
    Dim Town As Variant
    Dim County As Variant
    Dim Postcode As Variant
    Dim EmailAddress As Variant
    Dim HomePhone As Variant
    Dim MobilePhone As Variant
    Dim CurrentInsurer As Variant
    Dim PolicyMembers As Variant
    Dim CPMonthlyPremium As Variant
    Dim PaymentFrequency As Variant
    Dim CPOutpatientCover As Variant
    Dim CPExcessAmount As Variant
    Dim CPNotes As Variant
    Dim Notes As Variant
    Dim AssignedLGAgent As Variant
    Dim TransferredTick As Variant
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object
    
With Forms("RecordViewerF")
    RecordID = !RecordID
    Title = !Title.Column(1)
    FirstName = !FirstName
    LastName = !LastName
    Address1 = !Address1
    Address2 = !Address2
    Town = !Town
    County = !County
    Postcode = !Postcode
    EmailAddress = !EmailAddress
    HomePhone = !HomePhone
    MobilePhone = !MobilePhone
    CurrentInsurer = !CurrentInsurer.Column(1)
    PolicyMembers = !PolicyMembers.Column(1)
    CPMonthlyPremium = !CPMonthlyPremium
    PaymentFrequency = !PaymentFrequency.Column(1)
    CPOutpatientCover = !CPOutpatientCover.Column(1)
    CPExcessAmount = !CPExcessAmount.Column(1)
    TransferredTick = !TransferredTick
    CPNotes = !CPNotes
    Notes = !Notes
    AssignedLGAgent = !AssignedLGAgent.Column(1)
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    With objEmail
    .To = "@intelligentpmi.co.uk; @intelligentpmi.co.uk; @intelligentpmi.co.uk"
    .Subject = RecordID & ", " & Title & " " & LastName & ", from: " & AssignedLGAgent & " (automated transfer email)"
    .HTMLBody = "<p>" & "Name: " & Title & " " & FirstName & " " & LastName & "<p>" & "Address: " & "<p>" & Address1 & "<p>" & Address2 & "<p>" & Town & "<p>" & County & "<p>" & Postcode & "<p>" & "Home: " & HomePhone & "<p>" & "Mobile: " & MobilePhone & "<p>" & "Email Address: " & EmailAddress & "<p>" & "Insurer: " & CurrentInsurer & "<p>" & "Policy Members: " & PolicyMembers & "<p>" & "Premium: " & CPMonthlyPremium & " " & PaymentFrequency & "<p>" & "Outpatient Level: " & CPOutpatientCover & "<p>" & "Excess: " & CPExcessAmount & "<p>" & "Policy Notes: " & CPNotes & "<p>" & "ContactNotes: " & Notes
    .Display
    
    End With
     Set objEmail = Nothing
     Set objOutlook = Nothing
     
     LGOutcome = 2
     SalesAdvisor = 1
     OriginalTransferDate = Now()
     TransferredTick = 0.1
     
End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Either `True` (Yes) or `False` (No) which is the same with `-1` and `0` respectively. To reverse the value, `TransferredTick = Not TransferredTick`.

Comment: Hi Kostas, thank you for the quick response, I've tried changing "transferredTick = 0.1" to the 3 options you suggested and none of them have worked, everything still works except the check box remains unticked. Could it be a problem with defining the check box as a variant?

Comment: ah, that will save time. thank you

Comment: No, the problem is that you're setting the recordset value. Try `Forms.RecordViewerF.YourCheckboxControlName.Value = True`. And try to have different names between the controls and the recordset fields. To see changes made in the recordset, you need to save the record and requery the form.

Comment: fantastic, that sorted it. thanks for your help

Comment: @KostasK. in VBA only Variant type variable can accept Null.

Comment: @June7 You're right, got mixed up with .net.